# So very lost on initializing const objects

Tags: objective-c, constants

I have tried many times to understand the const keyword, but it just doesn't work out for me.

I want to declare an object that cannot be changed, which is to say, a constant object.  For example, in the .h file:

```
extern MyClass *use_this_object;
```

and in the .m file:

```
MyClass *use_this_object;

+ (void) Initialize {
  use_this_object = [MyClass new];
}
```

Now, where can I put a const so that other classes can access `use_this_object` but not modify it (assuming `MyClass` is immutable), while the `MyClass` class can initialize the variable?

Is this even possible?  Or should I be using a static method to retrive the constant and not declare it extern at all?

Comment: Well, I thought it might apply in C as well, because they are rather similar in many respects.  But obviously not in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "const object" in Objective-C. There are const *pointers* and there are immutable objects. A const pointer to an immutable object is what you're talking about, but you can't allocate those at run time.

For objects that can be allocated at compile time (and I only know of one, `NSString`), you can do this:

```
NSString * const kMyString = @"string";
```

This is a constant pointer to an (immutable) `NSString`. You read these things right-to-left.

To create what you want, you need a function or method with an internal `static` like this:

```
+ (Something *)something {
  static Something *something = nil;
  if (! something) {
      something = [Something new];
  }
  return something;
}
```

This is preferable to using globals anyway for things other than true constants (like strings and integers).

It is up to you to make sure that `Something` is immutable.

**EDIT** Just a note about the above code. This is just an example of how to create a static object at runtime. There are many ways to do it with various trade-offs including using `+initialize` with a file static (which is currently my preferred way to create a singleton). Don't take the above code as the one-and-only-way. It's just the way that is closest to `const` because no other part of the program can get directly to the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I’d use the static method, seems much simpler.